# Как при переходе на страницу "подскроллить сайт" к блоку с определённым id

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть ссылка вида `/cabinet/tasks/set-school-classes?role=research_coordinator_oo#12146`
где `12146` это `<div id="12146">`

нужно при переходе по этой ссылке скролить страницу к этому `<div>` , беря `id` именно из url

как написать это на jquery? точнее как его получить в jquery?
в общем вот такой есть набросок (нерабочий естественно)

```
  $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("здесь ид блока").offset().top  // класс объекта к которому приезжаем
  }, 1200); // Скорость прокрутки
```

как его дописать?

Comment: О_о оно же и так само должно скроллиться, нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь еще нужно прикрутить проверку, есть ли хэш при загрузке url.
Но в целом это выглядит вот так.

```js
const hash = window.location.hash // получаем хэш 
const target = hash.substring(1); // удаляем знак #

$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
}, 1200);
```

Пример для продакшн с проверкой на хэш:

```js
$(function() {
  const hash = window.location.hash
  
  if (hash) {
    const target = hash.substring(1);
    
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 1200);
  }
});
```